# Why can't I succesfully read file data to a struct array

Tags: c++, struct, deserialization

I am writing a program based on the battleship board game for my C++ final, The problem I'm currently working on is how to manage user accounts. I have to allow users to use the same account every time they play and keep track of their win/loss record. I'm able to write the data to a file but I need to read it back in when a player logs back in and then sort it to find their user name. I'm stuck at this part.

this is a the file I'm using, its read as username,wins,losses:

```
Rocky 0 0
Bob 0 0
dave 0 0
Jerry 0 0
Bert 0 0
Ernie 0 0
Marcus 0 0
```

edit: this is the output I'm getting repeating many more times though

```
-858993460
-858993460

-858993460
-858993460

-858993460
-858993460
```

UserData is a struct

```
//begin create/find account function
userData createAccount(userData ud){

    //local variables
    int playerOption;

    //creates object to open files
    ifstream infile;

    //creates object to open files
    ofstream outfile;

    do {
        cout << "Do you have an existing account?" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 1 for yes or 2 for no:" << endl;
        cin >> playerOption;
    }
    while (playerOption >= 3 || playerOption <= 0);



    if (playerOption == 1){
        cout << "Enter user name:" << endl;
        cin >> ud.name;

        //opens file in read mode
        infile.open("userData.dat");

        //tests to make sure the file is open
        if (!infile){
            cout << "File open failure!";
        }


        //creates array of user data
        userData userDataArray [SIZE];

        //reads data from file into array until end of file
        int i=0;
        while(i<SIZE){
            infile >> userDataArray[i].name;
            infile >> userDataArray[i].wins;
            infile >> userDataArray[i].losses;
            i++;
        }

        ///test output
        int j=0;
        while (j<SIZE){
            cout << userDataArray[j].name << endl;
            cout << userDataArray[j].wins << endl;
            cout << userDataArray[j].losses << endl;
            j++;
        }
        //end test output


        //closes file
        infile.close();
    }

    else if(playerOption == 2){
        cout << "Enter user name:" << endl;
        cin >> ud.name;
        ud.wins = 0;
        ud.losses = 0;

        //opens file in write mode
        outfile.open("userData.dat",ios::app);

        //tests to make sure the file is open
        if (!outfile){
            cout << "File open failure!";
        }

        //writes userData struct to file
        outfile << ud.name << " " << ud.wins << " " << ud.losses << endl;

        //closes file
        outfile.close();
    }

    return ud;

//end create/find account function
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what is "not working"?

Comment: It's printing out "-858993460
-858993460

-858993460
-858993460

-858993460
-858993460" instead of user names and integers for win/loss

Comment: Could you simplify your code to a minimal test case and show us a simplified definition of `userData` ?

Comment: Add error checking (error printing) to your file reads.

Comment: Did you have a look at the file itself? Does it hold the correct values?

Comment: yes.... the file is written by the program and the correct values and spaces are being written there

Comment: Then please delete the serialization part of your code and include a test file to read.

Comment: retaged: i doubt visual studio has any part in the problem. Added `struct` and `deserialization`, although that part doesn't seem to be the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what a minimal example looks like, and it works perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct { string name; int wins; int losses; } userData;

void createAccount(){
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("userData.dat");

    userData userDataArray[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        infile >> userDataArray[i].name;
        infile >> userDataArray[i].wins;
        infile >> userDataArray[i].losses;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        cout << userDataArray[i].name << endl;
        cout << userDataArray[i].wins << endl;
        cout << userDataArray[i].losses << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    createAccount();
}
```

Output:

```
Rocky
0
0
Bob
0
0
dave
0
0
```

So you should simplify your code bit by bit, until it works. Or start from a simple code like mine and build your way up to achieve the functionality you need.

You initial question was "Why can't I succesfully read file data to a struct array", but apparently that is not the problem.

For a start, what is the value of `SIZE` ? If you say the output is very long, you might have set `size` to a value much higher than the number of serialized data in the file, and you are printing a lot of uninitialized data.

Comment: You're right..I dropped SIZE from 300 to 10 and that's exactly what was happening...It was reading the data correctly and just scrolled out before I could see it... I need to find another way to signify end of file other than using a sentinel...or not...either way I can move forward to sorting the data now...Thank You!

Comment: May i suggest you add a counter at the top of your file to indicate how many structs are serialized. You can start by reading the counter and then use it in a loop. However that solution will break the `ios::app` when you append, because you need to increment the counter. Good luck and happy coding.